# Setting koma script option from within ones own class file

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I asked a question on how to set up the footer in koma script to get the right distance between page number and text using scrlayer-scrpage (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559567/18561). The solution works if komascript is loaded directly, but I cannot get it to work if I load komascript in a separate class file.

```
%    \documentclass[footlines=1]{scrbook}            
\documentclass{debug-langscibook}            

%    \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\usepackage{scrpage2}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

This is the self-defined class:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Class
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\LoadClass[
  footlines=1,
  ]{scrbook}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%    Header and footer
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\usepackage{scrpage2}
```

The footline=1 option is simply ignored.

Comment: If you put `footlines=1` in to the optional argument to `\documentclass` it is a global option and will be picked up by packages as well, whereas it is only a local option to `scrbook` if you put it in the argument of `\LoadClass`. You could use `\KOMAoptions` after you loaded `scrlayer-scrpage`, or put a `\PassOptionsToPackage{footlines=1}{scrlayer-scrpage}` before you load `scrlayer-scrpage`, or put it in the optional argument of `\documentclass` for your own class as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `footline` and option `footheight` are options of package `typearea` which is loaded by the KOMA-Script classes automatically. But if you use this options in the argument of `\LoadClass`, package `typearea` will not see them.

You could use either

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{footlines=1}{typearea}
\LoadClass{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

or

```latex
\LoadClass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{footlines=1}
\recalctypearea
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
```